# Add a textview to the listview

Tags: android

Friends. I am doing one android application. In that application I want to show **total number of list items** as a final column. so my question is "Is it possible  to add a `TextView` to the `ListView` as final column.?" like the following image.

[image]

I was searching lot through internet friends. But the solution is mostly like combine *two* `ListView` and add views *dynamically* to the `ListView`. Thats why I need your help friends.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
list.addFooterView(v).
```

Make sure that you are adding the view before you setting the adapter to the list. For more [check out this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
list.addFooterView(textView);
```

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    ListView v = getListView();   
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("total number of items: 114");
    v.addFooterView(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution is to count the number of list items before setting your adapter, with `yourTable.length();`

Then maybe you can add a row in this table with your "Total Number of items xxx" instead of the date and an empty title.